# How to solve circular dependency?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, circular-dependency, dependency-analysis

I have three classes that are circular dependant to each other:

TestExecuter execute requests of TestScenario  and save a report file using ReportGenerator class.
So:

- TestExecuter depends on ReportGenerator to generate the report
- ReportGenerator depends on TestScenario and on parameters set from TestExecuter.
- TestScenario depends on TestExecuter.

Can't figure out how to remove thoses dependencies.

```java
public class TestExecuter {

  ReportGenerator reportGenerator;  

  public void getReportGenerator() {
     reportGenerator = ReportGenerator.getInstance();
     reportGenerator.setParams(this.params);
     /* this.params several parameters from TestExecuter class example this.owner */
  }

  public void setTestScenario (TestScenario  ts) {
     reportGenerator.setTestScenario(ts); 
  }

  public void saveReport() {
     reportGenerator.saveReport();    
  }

  public void executeRequest() {
    /* do things */
  }
}
```

```java
public class ReportGenerator{
    public static ReportGenerator getInstance(){}
    public void setParams(String params){}
    public void setTestScenario (TestScenario ts){}
    public void saveReport(){}
}
```

```java
public class TestScenario {

    TestExecuter testExecuter;

    public TestScenario(TestExecuter te) {
        this.testExecuter=te;
    }

    public void execute() {
        testExecuter.executeRequest();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
      TestExecuter te = new TestExecuter();
      TestScenario ts = new TestScenario(te);

      ts.execute();
      te.getReportGenerator();
      te.setTestScenario(ts);
      te.saveReport()
    }
}
```

EDIT: in response to an answer, more details about my TestScenario class:

```java
public class TestScenario {
    private LinkedList<Test> testList;
    TestExecuter testExecuter;

    public TestScenario(TestExecuter te) {
        this.testExecuter=te;
    }

    public void execute() {
        for (Test test: testList) {
            testExecuter.executeRequest(test); 
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
  private String testName;
  private String testResult;
}

public class ReportData {
/*shall have all information of the TestScenario including the list of Test */
    }
```

An example of the xml file to be generated in case of a scenario containing two tests:

```java
<testScenario name="scenario1">
   <test name="test1">
     <result>false</result>
   </test>
   <test name="test1">
     <result>true</result>
   </test>
</testScenario >
```

Comment: Try identify your objects going backwards asking *what* (object) do you need for previous one to work - for example: `File(filename).write(Report); Report = XMLResult(ResultData).toString(); ResultData = TestSuite(SingleTestLogic).execute(TestDataIterator(TestDetailsList))`

Comment: @sabrina2020, since A is in B as B is in A, shouldn't they be one and the same?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Technically, you can resolve any cyclic dependency by using interfaces, as shown in the other answers. However, I recommend to rethink your design. I think it is not unlikely you can **avoid** the need for additional interfaces completely, while your design becomes even simpler.

I guess it is not necessary for a `ReportGenerator` to depend on a `TestScenario` directly. `TestScenario` seems to have two responsibilites: it is used for test execution, and it works also as a container for the results. This is a violation of the SRP. Interestingly, by resolving that violation, you will get rid of the cyclic dependency as well.

So instead of letting the report generator grab data from the test scenario, pass the data explicitly by using some value object. That means, replace

```
   reportGenerator.setTestScenario(ts);
```

by some code like

```
reportGenerator.insertDataToDisplay(ts.getReportData());
```

The method `getReportData` needs to have a return type like `ReportData`, a value object which works as a container for the data to be displayed in the report. `insertDataToDisplay` is a method which expects an object of exactly that type.

This way, `ReportGenerator` and `TestScenario` will both depend on `ReportData`, which depends on nothing else, and the first two classes do not depend on each other any more.

As a second approach: to resolve the SRP violation let `TestScenario` be responsible for holding the results of a test execution, but not for calling the test executer. Consider to reorganize the code so not the test scenario accesses the test executer, but the test executer is started from outside and writes the results back into the `TestScenario` object. In the example you showed us, that will be possible by making the access to `LinkedList<Test>` inside of `TestScenario` public, and by moving the `execute` method from `TestScenario` to somewhere else, maybe directly into a `TestExecuter`, maybe into a new class `TestScenarioExecuter`.

That way, `TestExecuter` will depend on `TestScenario` and `ReportGenerator`, `ReportGenerator` will depend on `TestScenario`, too , but `TestScenario` will depend on nothing else.

And finally, a third approach: `TestExecuter` has too many responsibilities, too. It is responsible for executing tests as well as for providing a `TestScenario` to a `ReportGenerator`. Put these two responsibilities into two separate classes, and your cyclic dependency will vanish again.

There may be more variants to approach your problem, but I hope you get the general idea: your core problem are classes with **too many responsibilities**. Solve that problem, and you will get rid of the cyclic dependency automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I need all information in TestScenario to be able to generate my report at the end :(

Comment: @sabrina2020: and what hinders you from putting all that information into `ReportData`? You may consider to edit your question and explain a little bit more detailed what happens inside of `saveReport`.

Comment: Actually my TestScenario contains a list of Test and I want all information in a report xml file so the ReportData shall have it all in this case, I will edit my answer for more details, thanks!

Comment: +1: You had me at `interfaces`.

Comment: @sabrina2020: I added two different approaches to my answer, pick the one which suits your needs best.

Answer (score 15):

By using interfaces you can solve the circular dependency.

**Current design:**

[image]

**Proposed design:**

[image]

In the proposed design concrete classes don't depend on other concrete classes but only on abstractions (interfaces).

**Important:**

You have to use the **creational pattern** of your choice (maybe a factory) to avoid perfoming `new` of any concrete classes inside any other concrete class or calling `getInstance()`. Only the factory will have dependencies on concrete classes. Your `Main` class could serve as factory if you think a dedicated factory would be overkill. For example you can inject a `ReportGenerator` into `TestExecuter` instead of calling `getInstance()` or `new`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `TestExecutor` only uses `ReportGenerator` internally, you should be able to define an interface for it, and refer to the interface in `TestScenario`. Then `TestExecutor` depends on `ReportGenerator`, `ReportGenerator` depends on `TestScenario`, and `TestScenario` depends on `ITestExecutor`, which doesn't depend on anything.

Ideally you'd be defining interfaces for all your classes and expressing dependencies through them, but this is the smallest change which will solve your problem.