# How to easily avoid circular dependencies

Tags: architecture, layers, circular-dependency

In a legacy project's service layer, there are tens of *service* classes and among them there is one service, `UtilityService` using 2 other services:

```
class UtilityService{
    private UserService userService;
    private ContactService contactService;
    //some methods using userService and contactService
}
```

This `UtilityService` is used in the *controller* level classes with other services. Some *controller* classes have *depednencies* on both `UtilityService` and `UserService` since some methods in `UserService` are needed in the `controller` class but they are not delegated to `UtilityService`:

```
class CustomerController {
    private UserService userService;
    private UtilityService utilityService;
    public List<Customer> getAvailableCustomers() {
      //here both userService and utilityService are in use
    }

}
```

IMO, the dependencies on both `UtilityService` and `ContactService` in one *controller* class are subject to *circular references* => **Question**: how to improve the code structure so that *circular references* can be easily avoided?

Comment: It's hard to say much more without seeing the full structure of your code, but my instant take is that if you can't find a better name for something than `UtilityService` (which really conveys no more information than `ThingThing`), you should consider whether that class should exist at all.

Comment: Whether a circular dependency exists is a factual question and not a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Rui can you describe what *you* think a circular dependency is? (and why you think it's bad?)

Comment: @Rui: if you like to describe what a circular dependency is according to your understanding, please edit your question, don't try to edit such an explanation into my answer.

Answer (score 36):

The premise of this question is wrong - the example does not show a circular dependency.

The dependencies are

```
       CustomerController 
       |              |
       V              |
    UtilityService    |
       |     |        |
       |     V        V   
       |     UserService
       V
      ContactService
```

This is a directed acyclic graph - there are no cycles involved.

The fact the transitive dependency from CustomerController to UserService by UtilityService manifests itself explicitly as a direct dependency is not an issue, as long as it is not a design goal to make UtilityService a facade for accessing the service layer by the controller layer. The examples you gave show no indication for this.

For code, however, which really contains circular dependencies, have a look at this older SWE.SE question: [How to solve circular dependency?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/306483)

This [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/306496) shows how to resolve any kind of cyclic dependency by introducing interfaces. This [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/306489) shows how cyclic dependencies can be avoided in certain cases by creating smaller components with less responsibilities.

Note also resolving cyclic dependencies is not an end in itself, it is means to an end. A certain amount of cyclic dependencies (within one layer of a layered architecture, of course) can be acceptable, as long as testability and build times are not affected too much.

Comment: Years ago my codebase switched to interface files for each of the classes to resolve cyclic dependencies, and it took years for us to realize we did it wrong. The right thing is to create *event listener* interfaces. All the code depends on the event listener interfaces, and never on each other. With this, our tests are getting rapidly smaller and faster and less flaky, and the code is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score -8):

One of the easiest ways is to make sure that you have a single direction to your references between layers. ie

Presentation -> Controllers -> Services -> Data

In your example you have one service reference another. BAD! you could move the logic up to a controller or add another layer

Presentation -> Controllers -> Application -> Services -> Data

Edit: Obviously, your question doesn't technically show a "circular reference" I am assuming you want a solution to the situation you show in your code examples, where you have unknown numbers of instances of the same service and potentially infinite loops or problems with instantiation where ServiceA calls ServiceB calls ServiceA again etc

Comment: Since when is it wrong to have references inside one layer?

Comment: Since someone needed any easy way to avoid "circular dependencies"

Comment: I'll be honest - this looks like a nigthmare to maintain

Comment: This answer might be better if it addressed why that would be worth it? You could equally avoid circular dependencies by putting all your source into a single giant class but I don't think that would be worth it and isn't a good idea.

Comment: You would avoid compile time circular references, but here the OP is obvs asking about a more complex situation. Dunno why i get 6 down votes for basically a simple premise in most popular architectures and a sure fire way to avoid any issues for beginners

Comment: We don't yet have a definition of "circular dependency". From what I read in the question, Rui might want that the dependency-graph is a tree, which would not be guaranteed by the level-x+1-constraint you are suggesting.

Comment: Not one of the downvoters, but it's very common for services to use other services. Or do none of your services use a logging service? ;p

Comment: Curious about what your Application layer is though--I've never heard the term used in a MPC architecture.

Comment: Side question--I've been asked and couldn't answer before, but in my experience, it's common to use Services in MVP, MVC, MVVM, etc. But does that make it a new/separate pattern?

Comment: @Mars the rule should guarantee a tree structure with no loops, which are obvs a danger if you have services calling services as in this case. i would put a logging service in the data layer myself. the application layer name comes from clean arch i believe, but its just an extra layer where you can put the "mashaling of services" logic and maintain the rule. Obvs you can have two things on the same layer call each other, but if you can avoid it then you have "an easy way to avoid circular dependencies"